# Ubuntu-Image fails to build image

Tags: 20.04, snap, ubuntu-core, snap-store

I am using Ubuntu-Image to build an image for ubuntu with several snaps as outlined here:
https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/using-ubuntu-image

I have been able to build images without issue for a while now, but today out of nowhere, the process fails for all of my images (including ones that have had no modifications).

The timestamp is injected, and valid, the authority id was removed for this posting. The assertion is properly created.

Here is an example of my JSON

```json
{
    "type": "model",
    "series": "16",
    "authority-id": "**********",
    "brand-id": "**********",
    "model": "ubuntu-core-20-pi-arm64",
    "architecture": "arm64",
    "timestamp": "%TIMESTAMP%",
    "base": "core20",
    "grade": "dangerous",
    "system-user-authority": [
        "**********"
    ],
    "snaps": [
        {
            "name": "tot-pi",
            "type": "gadget"
        },
        {
            "name": "bare",
            "type": "base",
            "default-channel": "latest/stable",
            "id": "EISPgh06mRh1vordZY9OZ34QHdd7OrdR"
        },
        {
            "name": "pi-kernel",
            "type": "kernel",
            "default-channel": "20/stable",
            "id": "jeIuP6tfFrvAdic8DMWqHmoaoukAPNbJ"
        },
        {
            "name": "core20",
            "type": "base",
            "default-channel": "latest/stable",
            "id": "DLqre5XGLbDqg9jPtiAhRRjDuPVa5X1q"
        },
        {
            "name": "core",
            "type": "core",
            "default-channel": "latest/stable",
            "id": "99T7MUlRhtI3U0QFgl5mXXESAiSwt776"
        },
        {
            "name": "snapd",
            "type": "snapd",
            "default-channel": "latest/stable",
            "id": "PMrrV4ml8uWuEUDBT8dSGnKUYbevVhc4"
        },
        {
            "name": "ubuntu-frame",
            "type": "app",
            "default-channel": "latest/stable",
            "id": "BPZbvWzvoMTrpec4goCXlckLe2IhfthK"
        },
        {
            "name": "mesa-core20",
            "type": "app",
            "default-channel": "latest/stable",
            "id": "pDDsAW9ifzZnogboHJu3udsA6LsbGeGP"
        },
        {
            "name": "gnome-3-38-2004",
            "type": "app",
            "default-channel": "latest/stable",
            "id": "rw36mkAjdIKl13dzfwyxP87cejpyIcct"
        },
        {
            "name": "gtk-common-themes",
            "type": "app",
            "default-channel": "latest/stable",
            "id": "jZLfBRzf1cYlYysIjD2bwSzNtngY0qit"
        },
        {
            "name": "network-manager",
            "type": "app",
            "default-channel": "20/stable",
            "id": "RmBXKl6HO6YOC2DE4G2q1JzWImC04EUy"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use the following command to generate the image after other steps to sign the model.

```bash
ubuntu-image snap ubuntu-core-20-pi-arm64.model --snap pi_20-1_arm64.snap --snap wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk -o $OUTPUT_PATH/$FILE_NAME
```

Everything works ok, until the following error:

```
Fetching snapd (20674)
Fetching network-manager (865)
Fetching pi-kernel (732)
Fetching core20 (2107)
Fetching bare (5)
Fetching core (16204)
Fetching ubuntu-frame (5795)
Fetching mesa-core20 (154)
Fetching gnome-3-38-2004 (145)
Fetching gtk-common-themes (1535)
Fetching wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk (101)
error: prerequisites need to be added explicitly: cannot use snap "ubuntu-frame": default provider "mesa-core20" or any alternative provider for content "" is missing
```

If I remove ubuntu frame, I run into the same error for the next snap in line and removing that snap results in yet another error until there are no more snaps left. **This model and the scripts have worked fine for over a year until today, some with no changes at all.**

Any help would be appreciated. This started out of nowhere, and perhaps I accidently made a change somewhere, or there is some outage or issue with ubuntu-image or a recent build of one or more snaps. I am at a dead end here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation and reviewing the source code where the error is generated, and checking the version installed, I found that I was ubuntu-image installed from apt (if you ran `apt install ubuntu-image` etc.).

The Apt version has not been updated for a very long time, so after checking the snap version, it was updated in the last week.

To fix this, I uninstalled the apt version, and installed the snap version:

```bash
    sudo apt remove ubuntu-image
    sudo snap install ubuntu-image
```

And just like that, things are working. I had to modify my script to capitalize the -o parameter to -O which was a good sign.

The behavior of -O is different now as well, expect it to output the .img file as the volume name specified in the gadget snap, and not the file name passed in using -O, it will instead create a folder with the exact name (in my case ubuntu.img/pi.img)

I didn't sleep last night, but I did solve the problem. I hope this post is helpful to others in the future. :)